# Howto make javascript target blank

Tags: javascript, rss, target

I parse feeds with rss displayer javascript. This is the script in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//USAGE SYNTAX: new rssdisplayer("divid", "rssurl", numberofitems, "displayoptions")
new rssdisplayer("voorpagina", "http://news.google.nl/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&topic=h&output=rss", 15, "")
</script>
```

Is there a way to set the target at _blank???
Thank you.

Comment: How should we know?  What is `rssdisplayer`?  It could be anything.  You should contact the person that wrote it.

Comment: rss displayer is a javascript for parsing rss feeds. The problem is that the output is not target blank...

Comment: That isn't nearly specific enough.  Got a link?  The answer lies in how this component is written, and we don't even know what you're using.

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed.shtml .

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly RssDisplayer create HTML view by parameters you pass to it. For example, if you call

```
new rssdisplayer("voorpagina", "http://news.google.nl/newspz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&topic=h&output=rss", 15, "")
```

It must produce something like this:

```
<a href="http://news.google.nl/newspz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&topic=h&output=rss">voorpagina</a>
<hr/>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m1.html">news 1</a>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m2.html">news 2</a>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m3.html">news 3</a>
```

But you need:

```
<a href="http://news.google.nl/newspz=1&cf=all&ned=nl_nl&hl=nl&topic=h&output=rss">voorpagina</a>
<hr/>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m1.html" TARGET="_blank">news 1</a>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m2.html" TARGET="_blank">news 2</a>
<a href="http://news.google.nl/m3.html" TARGET="_blank">news 3</a>
```

I see three ways to get it:

- Look at RssDisplayer code.  May be it have a parameter to display all news as '_blank'
- If it doesn't have you can change the code of RssDisplayer and add this parameter by yourself.
- Or you can write the JS code which will run after RssDisplayer and add to all links TARGET attribute.